# Python3 module pakaging files structure and init file

Tags: python-3.x, module, structure, init

I have Python module with single file and single function inside the file. I've uploaded it to pypi, and I used following structure to package it, but when I called the function which it inside module file I received this error:

```
AttributeError: module 'effInput' has no attribute 'ask'
```

('ask' is name of function).

Module package structure :

```
|--effInput
    |--__init__. py
    |--effInput.py (module file) 
|--setup.py
|--readme.txt
|--LICENSE
```

**init**.py file:

```
import effInput
name="EffInput"
```

What I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do it that way you have to call `effInput.effInput.ask` instead of `effInput.ask`. If you did `from effInput import *` in your `__init__.py` it should work as intended.

Comment: And I should put __init__.py file in package root or beside module file?

Comment: Beside module file.